# Load raster mapserver into QGIS 2.18- Error

Tags: raster, qgis-plugins, mapserver, error, qgis-2.18

I try to load this mapserver raster into QGIS, using ArcGIS REST API Connector plugin:

http://www.sol-israel.co.il/arcgis/rest/services/ORTHO_LACHISH_Mapi/MapServer/0

but i get an error- how can i do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong panel and the wrong URL.

Go into Layer->Add Layer->Add ArcGIS MapServer Layer
Create a new server connection and use this URL: 
http://www.sol-israel.co.il/arcgis/rest/services/ORTHO_LACHISH_Mapi/MapServer

You can now load the layer 0 you were interested in.